# I'm worried that I'm training my model wrong

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, perceptron

So I'm trying to classify some fashion mnist like photos into either boots or sneakers. I'm using a perception from sklearn to do so. The data set is a CSV containing pixel values. The model is trained through cross validation. Here is the code:

```
def perceptron_train(ds,target,data,splits):
    clf = linear_model.Perceptron()
    kf = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=splits,shuffle=True)
    X = data
    y = target

    accuracy_model = []
    training_times = []

    for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
        X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index],X.iloc[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
        train_start = time.time()#time training time
        model = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
        train_stop = time.time()
        overall_train_time = train_stop-train_start
        training_times.append(overall_train_time)

        #test_start = time.time()
        accuracy_model.append(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test,model.predict(X_test),normalize=True)*100)
        #test_stop = time.time()
    print(np.mean(accuracy_model))
    print(np.mean(training_times))
```

What I'm worried about in particular is this line:

```
X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index],X.iloc[test_index]
y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
```

The accuracy is very high and I'm worried that I'm either overfitting or I'm training on the wrong part of the dataset. Sorry, I'm just learning cross-validation and just looking for some confirmation that this is not wrong.
Thank you

Comment: Everything looks okay to me.  How high is "very high"?  Are you getting results that are competitive with SOTA models?

Comment: @zachdj around 98%. Thanks for the feedback, I was just concerned that with the accuracy so high.

Comment: Hm that is unusually high for a single perceptron trained on fashion MNIST.  So you're right to be concerned.  But the dataset slicing logic looks fine to me ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯